# When my gums are swollen, flossing a lot reduces and fixes up my gums. Why?

Tags: dentistry, inflammation, gums

Is it just because when I don't floss for a long time (few weeks to a few months) the food trapped between my teeth causes bacteria that cause my gums to swell up?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

Although there is *limited scientific evidence* for flossing, it unquestionably **does physically remove plaque between teeth**, which cannot be removed with the bristles of a toothbrush. If it is not removed, the plaque in turn can cause gingivitis and ultimatly periodontitis (formation of pockets).

**To answere your question weather there are other contributing factors :**

- **Flossing possibly stimulates the gums physicaly, and makes them become firmer**, but currently there is very little in the way of evidence for that.
- Another possibility is that **by flossing regularly, you also use simultaneously other means of cleaning teeth**, such as regular teeth brushing and mouth rinces)

Source:
http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/24353078 (limited scientific evidence)